# Go: Initialize a map with automatic return values

Tags: go

If I declare a `map[string]string` return value in a function definition, do I have to make it before using it, just like if I had instead declared it in the function body? http://play.golang.org/p/iafZbG2ZbY

```
package main

import "fmt"

func fill() (a_cool_map map[string]string) {
    // This fixes it: a_cool_map = make(map[string]string)
    a_cool_map["key"] = "value"
    return
}
func main() {
    a_cool_map := fill()
    fmt.Println(a_cool_map)
}
```

`panic: runtime error: assignment to entry in nil map`

Comment: So how the solution for returning map from function ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [Map types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> The value of an uninitialized map is `nil`.
>
> A new, empty map value is made using the built-in function `make`.
>
> A `nil` map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be
>   added.

Yes.

Comment: So how the solution for returning map from function ?

Comment: @ImanTumorang I imagine its just doing a locally scoped map, `temp_map := make(map[string]string)` then populating the map and returning it. Which it should then be GC'ed.