# Difference in behavior between slices and maps

Tags: go

A related questions is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/12965872/6421681.

In go, you can do:

```
func numsInFactorial(n int) (nums []int) {
    // `nums := make([]int)` is not needed
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        nums = append(nums, i)
    }
    return
}
```

However,the following doesn't work:

```
func mapWithOneKeyAndValue(k int, v int) (m map[int]int) {
    m[k] = v
    return
}
```

An error is thrown:

`panic: assignment to entry in nil map`

Instead, you must:

```
func mapWithOneKeyAndValue(k int, v int) map[int]int {
    m := make(map[int]int)
    m[k] = v
    return
}
```

I can't find the documentation for this behavior.
I have read through all of effective go, and there's no mention of it there either.

I know that named return values are defined (i.e. memory is allocated; close to what `new` does) but not initialized (so `make` behavior isn't replicated). 

After some experimenting, I believe this behavior can be reduced into understanding the behavior of the following code:

```
func main() {
    var s []int // len and cap are both 0
    var m map[int]int

    fmt.Println(s) // works... prints an empty slice
    fmt.Println(m) // works... prints an empty map

    s = append(s, 10) // returns a new slice, so underlying array gets allocated
    fmt.Println(s) // works... prints [10]

    m[10] = 10 // program crashes, with "assignment to entry in nil map"
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

The issue seems that `append` likely calls `make` and allocates a new slice detecting that the capacity of `s` is `0`. However, `map` never gets an explicit initialization.

The reason for this SO question is two-pronged. First, I would like to document the behavior on SO. Second, why would the language allow non-initializing definitions of `slice` and `map`? With my experience with go so far, it seems to be a pragmatic language (i.e. unused variables lead to compilation failure, gofmt forces proper formatting), so it would make sense for it to prevent the code from compiling.

Comment: The documentation: [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec).

Comment: The behavior is well documented on SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgo%5D+assignment+to+entry+in+nil+map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to assign in nil slice by index - you will get "panic: runtime error: index out of range" (example: https://play.golang.org/p/-XHh1jNyn5g)

The only reason why append function works with nil, is that append function can do reallocation for the given slice.
For example, if you trying to to append 6th element to slice of 5 elements with current capacity 5, it will create the new array with new capacity, copy all the info from old one, and swap the data array pointers in the given slice. In my understanding, it is just golang implementation of dynamic arrays.

So, the nil slice is just a special case of slice with not enough capacity, so it would be reallocated on any append operation.

More details on https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Thanks! This clarifies some doubts I had!

Comment: @YoloVoe, please note that it's also perfectly OK to _search_ in an uninitialized map: it'll work as expected. So this answer correctly gets to the gist of the difference: the fact you can `append` to an uninitialized slice is sort-of a special case which was too convenient to leave out, I suppose. Please also consider that Go has a third type which requires initialization: a channel. Just like with maps, `nil` channels are valid in some cases, but you cannot send to them.

Answer (score 3):

From https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action

> A nil map behaves like an empty map when reading, but attempts to write to a nil map will cause a runtime panic; don't do that. To initialize a map, use the built in make function

It seems like a nil map is considered a valid empty map and that's the reason they don't allocate memory for it automatically.